# meta-analysis using metafor package. error at escalc function "object not found"

Tags: r, metafor

I am unsure of how to perform a meta-analysis by subgroups.

From what I understand `escalc` is needed to form the data structure.

I got the below code from ChatGPT (oops) and it doesn't run properly. The error message is

> Error: object 'ci_upper' not found

after running `escalc`. However, I am not sure why it is looking for an object when `ci.upper` is a column as I defined the 'data' argument in the `escalc` function and the error doesn't have an issue with the 'm1i' argument.

```
## install.packages("metafor")
library(metafor)

# Create a data frame with study results and subgroup information
study_results <- data.frame(
  study = c("Study 1", "Study 2", "Study 3", "Study 4", "Study 5"),
  subgroup = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
  mean = c(0.45, 0.78, 0.60, 0.85, 0.72),
  ci_lower = c(0.35, 0.70, 0.50, 0.75, 0.62),
  ci_upper = c(0.55, 0.86, 0.70, 0.95, 0.82)
)

# Create a formula specifying the mean and CI
formula <- formula(mean ~ 1 | subgroup)

# Create the data structure for subgroup meta-analysis
dat <- escalc(measure = "MN", m1i = mean, m2i = NA, sd1i = NA, sd2i = NA,
           ci.ub = ci_upper, ci.lb = ci_lower, data = study_results)

# Perform the subgroup meta-analysis
meta_analysis <- rma.mv(formula, data = dat)

# Print the subgroup meta-analysis results
print(meta_analysis)
```

Comment: ChatGPT is hallucinating. `ci.ub` is not even in the argument list of `escalc` (there is a `...`, but it doesn't get used this way).  Have you tried going back to ChatGPT and asking it to correct its answer?  Have you read through the [metafor documentation on subgroup analysis](https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:comp_two_independent_estimates) ?

Comment: As far as I can tell you should be providing `escalc` with vectors of standard deviations and sample sizes, not confidence bounds ...